# A Function isn't being called despite being called?

Tags: function, processing

I have a function that draws a grid of poles every 90 pixels however when i call it it doesn't output anything on screen. Here is the relevant code:

```java
void poles() {
  stroke(0, 0, 255);
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  strokeWeight(5);
  int polelocationX=90;
  int polelocationY=90;
  for (polelocationX=90; polelocationX<721; polelocationX+=90) {
    for (polelocationY=90; polelocationY<721; polelocationY+=90) {
      ellipse(polelocationX, polelocationY, 5, 5);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  poles();
  strokeWeight(1);
  collisionDetection();
  fizzyX+=movementX;
  fizzyY+=movementY;
  drawFizzy(fizzyX, fizzyY, fizzyRot);
}
```

Also this is an assignment so if this is just a stupid mistake i'm making id appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction instead of telling me the answer.

Comment: Please post your code as a [mcve] that we can actually run- in other words, take out the extra calls to `collisionDetection()` and `drawFizzy()` and make sure we can see the problem when we run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Try running this:

```
void setup(){
  size(800, 800);
}

void poles() {
  stroke(0, 0, 255);
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  strokeWeight(5);
  int polelocationX=90;
  int polelocationY=90;
  for (polelocationX=90; polelocationX<721; polelocationX+=90) {
    for (polelocationY=90; polelocationY<721; polelocationY+=90) {
      ellipse(polelocationX, polelocationY, 5, 5);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  poles();
}
```

This code draws a bunch of blue circles to the screen:

[image: blue circles]

If you aren't seeing them, then either your window is not large enough, or something in the code you haven't posted is clearing the screen.

You're going to have to [debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code to find exactly when the screen is being cleared. If you still need help, please post your code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to actually see the problem in a new question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.